# Como carregar imagem no ImageView com qualidade?

Tags: android, imageview, galeria

Olá, sou iniciante em programação android
Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que carrega imagens da galeria do usuário ou da câmera. Após selecionada a imagem eu utilizo um CropIntent para cortar a imagem. O problema é que não consigo dimensionar a imagem para caber no ImageView, além da imagem perder consideravelmente a qualidade.

Xml do ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="498dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="11dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp" />
```

Esse é o método que estou usando para cortar a imagem (O mesmo método para câmera e para imagens da galeria):

```
private void CropImage() {

    try{
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");

        CropIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX",400);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY",400);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX",3);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY",4);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded",true);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);

        startActivityForResult(CropIntent,1);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Você pode cogitar usar libraries como o Glide ou Picasso que fazem todo o trabalho de processar e carregar imagens em imageViews com a melhor qualidade possível em apenas 1 linha de código.

Comment: @Márcio, como faço isso? Basta importar essas Libraries?

Comment: Se colocar wrap_content na largura e na altura acho que resolveria esse problema de dimensão amigo

Comment: Eu fiz isso no ImageView. O componente se ajustou às bordas mas quando a imagem carrega, ela nunca encaixa e com a qualidade baixíssima.